# Elimination of the variables

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, variable, timing, run

I am trying to get an equation in terms of variable z by eliminating variables g0 and g1 but

Running below code is taking time forever

```
In[10]:=
y = 0.01; 
x = 0.057; 
n0 = 0; 
n1 = 1; 

gE0 = 1/g0 - Sqrt[1 + z^2/(Pi*(2*n0 + 1)*y + 4.4*x*Pi*g0)^2]; 
gE1 = 1/g1 - Sqrt[1 + z^2/(Pi*(2*n1 + 1)*y + 4.4*x*Pi*g1)^2]; 
sce0 = 2*Pi*0.01*(((2*n0 + 1)*Pi*0.01*(g0 - 1))/(((2*n0 + 1)*Pi*0.01 + 4.4*Pi*x)*((2*n0 + 1)*Pi*0.01 + 4.4*Pi*x*g0))) + 0.6431; sce1 = 2*Pi*0.01*(((2*n1 + 1)*Pi*0.01*(g1 - 1))/(((2*n1 + 1)*Pi*0.01 + 4.4*Pi*x)*((2*n1 + 1)*Pi*0.01 + 4.4*Pi*x*g1))); 

xed0 = Eliminate[{sce0 + sce1 == 0, gE0 == 0, gE1 == 0}, {g0, g1}]
```

Can someone simplify the above code to make it run quickly?

Comment: @Bill as far as I can tell `z` is only part of `gE0` and `gE1` in the first place? I think `sce0+sce1 == 0` simply serves to relate `g0` and `g1`.

Answer (score 3):

I think due to presence of radicals and denominators it is necessary to use exact (or at least high precision) arithmetic here.

```
y = 1/100;
x = 57/1000;
n0 = 0;
n1 = 1;
gE0 = 1/g0 - Sqrt[1 + z^2/(Pi*(2*n0 + 1)*y + 44/10*x*Pi*g0)^2];
gE1 = 1/g1 - Sqrt[1 + z^2/(Pi*(2*n1 + 1)*y + 44/10*x*Pi*g1)^2];
sce0 = 2*Pi*1/
    100*(((2*n0 + 1)*
       Pi*1/100*(g0 - 1))/(((2*n0 + 1)*Pi*1/100 + 
         44/10*Pi*x)*((2*n0 + 1)*Pi*1/100 + 44/10*Pi*x*g0))) + 
  6431/10000; sce1 = 
 2*Pi*1/100*(((2*n1 + 1)*
      Pi*1/100*(g1 - 1))/(((2*n1 + 1)*Pi*1/100 + 
        44/10*Pi*x)*((2*n1 + 1)*Pi*1/100 + 44/10*Pi*x*g1)));
ee = {sce0 + sce1, gE0, gE1};
```

The best way to eliminate variables is (alas) not with `Eliminate` (old old technology) but rather with `GroebnerBasis`. This even has a term order specialized for the task (though it's not really needed for this example).

```
GroebnerBasis[ee, {z}, {g0, g1}, 
 MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder]

(* Out[61]= {\
1087191781255118852432205908237263695371306687898414793553937916276108\
8539220193254804961973869866459309790986240000000000000000000000000000\
0000 \[Pi]^12 - 
  16268517781507860032737188758040268612029306311347272704315305344023\
7238897918646667014719758990108604114670256499168765721664552960000000\
0000000000000 \[Pi]^10 z^2 + 
  56738570910688790592087477644695709810029509155667904340817842292123\
9347364218848001458326552347662710033232181322227278181276799464374272\
0000000000000000 \[Pi]^8 z^4 - 
  76141485891245220851706051052591264935429766097405661030697946539103\
8953552797608365697130284448476658681402247606314777047661399316777410\
9663232000000000000 \[Pi]^6 z^6 + 
  48091488360591912991048204087577606236749539610147285181149875603683\
1168149454360470756370124698044548746378946137263823892891719840553131\
1438872323891200000000 \[Pi]^4 z^8 - 
  13638620110911998467924632042373320416852081399506396254722968526570\
9692816709167930328435898547536877212793691508552018024025486557122137\
3396013486887615269120000 \[Pi]^2 z^10 + 
  12072464157868041559939145105552971974917159481422285017012503613471\
4944532397589113777181341371047147797682391535913140689377031298240042\
493086282606446471987952001 z^12} *)
```

In finite precision we see there is a scale difference in the coefficients of the result that might also play a role in messing up any machine arithmetic attempt.

```
GroebnerBasis[N[ee, 25], {z}, {g0, g1}, 
 MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder]

(* Out[63]= {8.3235522*10^-16 - 1.26197511*10^-9 z^2 + 
  4.4594515*10^-7 z^4 - 0.000060635178 z^6 + 0.0038803579 z^8 - 
  0.111499842 z^10 + 1.00000000 z^12} *)
```

At the slightly lower precision of 20 digits this fails, with a message that there was not sufficient precision for the computation. Usijng machine arithmetic it silently gives a bad result of {1.} (meaning the expressions are not consistent). They are of course, but there is some amount of unwinding to do in order to make polynomials out of the radicals and denominators, and that can make for trouble at finite precision.

Comment: Actually it worked for n2 = 2 as well. Actually I am trying to solve for several n's equations self consistently and get the values for z where I need to have convergence after certain value of n. Is there any other way above problem can be performed so as to solve for value of z numerically? Already for nmax = 3 its running forever.

Comment: I do not know what `n2` or `nmax` are, or what would be the equations that are problematic.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm not sure why, but after rationalizing your equations, performing the elimination in sequence seemed to work:

```
y = Rationalize@0.01;
x = Rationalize@0.057;
n0 = 0;
n1 = 1;

gE0 = 1/g0 - 
   Sqrt[1 + z^2/(Pi*(2*n0 + 1)*y + Rationalize[4.4]*x*Pi*g0)^2];
gE1 = 1/g1 - 
   Sqrt[1 + z^2/(Pi*(2*n1 + 1)*y + Rationalize[4.4]*x*Pi*g1)^2];
sce0 = 2*Pi*(1/
     100)*(((2*n0 + 1)*
       Pi*(1/100)*(g0 - 1))/(((2*n0 + 1)*Pi*(1/100) + 
         Rationalize[4.4]*Pi*x)*((2*n0 + 1)*Pi/100 + 
         Rationalize[4.4]*Pi*x*g0))) + Rationalize[0.6431]; sce1 = 
 2*Pi*(1/100) (((2*n1 + 1)*
      Pi/100*(g1 - 1))/(((2*n1 + 1)*Pi/100 + 
        Rationalize[4.4]*Pi*x)*((2*n1 + 1)*Pi/100 + 
        Rationalize[4.4]*Pi*x*g1)));

xed0 = Eliminate[Eliminate[{sce0 + sce1 == 0, gE0 == 0, gE1 == 0}, {g1}], {g0}]
```

I'm not totally sure if this is "right", though. I'd take it with a grain of salt, as some one-way implications might have been used; this might not be an equivalent condition.

Comment: Interesting: changing the elimination order gives the same result, but doing both simultaneously does not terminate within say 1minute. May be worth reporting to Wolfram.

Answer (score 0):

Using the equations with rationalized constants.

The elimination can be simplified by equating the numerators of the LHS of each equation to zero.

```
(xed0 = Eliminate[{
     Numerator@Together[sce0 + sce1] == 0,
     Numerator@Together@gE0 == 0,
     Numerator@Together@gE1 == 0}, {g0, g1}]) // N

(* -1.52351*10^155 z^2 + 5.38366*10^157 z^4 - 7.32016*10^159 z^6 + 
  4.68455*10^161 z^8 - 1.34608*10^163 z^10 + 
  1.20725*10^164 z^12 == -1.00486*10^149 *)
```

This is the same as the result provided by `thorimur`

All of the roots are real

```
(solz = Solve[xed0, z]) // N

(* {{z -> -0.000812231}, {z -> 0.000812231}, {z -> -0.107171}, {z -> 
   0.107171}, {z -> -0.108051}, {z -> 0.108051}, {z -> -0.109268}, {z -> 
   0.109268}, {z -> -0.110874}, {z -> 0.110874}, {z -> -0.253192}, {z -> 
   0.253192}} *)
```

**EDIT:** To add additional equations use Daniel Lichtblau`s answer. For example,

```
Clear["Global`*"]

y = 1/100;
x = 57/1000;
```

Generalize the definitions

```
gE[n_Integer?NonNegative] := 
  1/g[n] - Sqrt[1 + z^2/(Pi*(2*n + 1)*y + 44/10*x*Pi*g[n])^2];

sce[0] = 2*
   Pi*1/100*((Pi*1/
        100*(g[0] - 1))/((Pi*1/100 + 44/10*Pi*x)*(Pi*1/100 + 
         44/10*Pi*x*g[0]))) + 6431/10000; 

sce[n_Integer?Positive] := 
 2*Pi*1/100*(((2*n + 1)*
      Pi*1/100*(g[n] - 1))/(((2*n + 1)*Pi*1/100 + 
        44/10*Pi*x)*((2*n + 1)*Pi*1/100 + 44/10*Pi*x*g[n])));

nmax = 2;

nValues = Range[0, nmax];

ee = {Total[sce /@ nValues], gE /@ nValues} // Flatten;

xed0 = GroebnerBasis[ee, {z}, g /@ nValues, 
    MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder];
```

Solving for `z`

```
(solz = Solve[xed0 == 0, z]) // N

(* {{z -> -0.000761198}, {z -> 0.000761198}, {z -> -0.000812231}, {z -> 
   0.000812231}, {z -> -0.00159705}, {z -> 
   0.00159705}, {z -> -0.00161735}, {z -> 
   0.00161735}, {z -> -0.00234828}, {z -> 
   0.00234828}, {z -> -0.00243983}, {z -> 
   0.00243983}, {z -> -0.101386}, {z -> 
   0.101386}, {z -> -0.102136}, {z -> 
   0.102136}, {z -> -0.102655}, {z -> 
   0.102655}, {z -> -0.10322}, {z -> 0.10322}, {z -> -0.103766}, {z ->
    0.103766}, {z -> -0.104686}, {z -> 
   0.104686}, {z -> -0.106111}, {z -> 
   0.106111}, {z -> -0.107184}, {z -> 
   0.107184}, {z -> -0.107299}, {z -> 
   0.107299}, {z -> -0.108065}, {z -> 
   0.108065}, {z -> -0.109282}, {z -> 
   0.109282}, {z -> -0.110889}, {z -> 0.110889}, {z -> -0.1439}, {z ->
    0.1439}, {z -> -0.145999}, {z -> 0.145999}, {z -> -0.15033}, {z ->
    0.15033}, {z -> -0.236372}, {z -> 
   0.236372}, {z -> -0.240141}, {z -> 
   0.240141}, {z -> -0.243525}, {z -> 
   0.243525}, {z -> -0.24677}, {z -> 0.24677}, {z -> -0.250029}, {z ->
    0.250029}, {z -> -0.253403}, {z -> 
   0.253403}, {z -> -0.438011}, {z -> 0.438011}} *)
```

As expected, the complexity grows with `nmax`

Comment: Thank you for the reply and it worked for n0=0 , n1=1 but if I add one more equation for n2=2 and repeat the same process its taking forever. In fact I have to vary n(let's say from n=0 -10) and solve for z.

Comment: What equation are you adding? We can only work with the information that you provide.

Comment: I am adding gE2 = 1/g2 - Sqrt[1 + z^2/(Pi*(2*n2 + 1)*y + Rationalize[4.4]*x*Pi*g2)^2];  sce2 = 2*Pi*(1/100)*(((2*n2 + 1)*(Pi/100)*(g2 - 1))/(((2*n2 + 1)*(Pi/100) + Rationalize[4.4]*Pi*x)*((2*n2 + 1)*(Pi/100) + Rationalize[4.4]*Pi*x*g2))); xed0 = N[Eliminate[{Numerator[Together[sce0 + sce1 + sce2]] == 0, Numerator[Together[gE0]] == 0, Numerator[Together[gE1]] == 0, Numerator[Together[gE2]] == 0}, {g0, g1, g2}]];  and other equations as above and this time I have to eliminate g2 as well